# Match the string for different string formating

Tags: c#, regex

I have a random .sql file with long sql query. I need to runtime get all table names from the insert sql statement to put into an array. I am able to get the table names (Inventory.tableA) out if the insert statement is in (one line) like the format below:

```
...
Insert into Inventory.tableA;
...
```

However, if the Insert statement is in multiple lines like below e.g.

```
Insert into 
Inventory.tableA;
```

OR

```
Insert into 
(blank line)
(blank line)
Inventory.tableA;
```

Then my query to retrieve the table name will fail. Can you advise how i can get the table name out from the long sql query which the insert statement can be in either one line or multiple lines? What is the best approach here?

Below is the c# query i tried which can handle for 1 line.

```
public List<string> GetAllTablesNames(string sp)
        {
            List<string> output = new List<string>();

            string[] contentSplit = sp.Split(new string[] { "INSERT INTO " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            for (int a = 1; a < contentSplit.Length; a++)
            {
                string[] sa_tableName = contentSplit[a].Substring(0, contentSplit[a].IndexOf("\r")).Trim().Split('.');

                    output.Add(sa_tableName[0] + "." + sa_tableName[1]);
            }

            return output.Distinct().ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Please show us the query that works on single lines and make your question title a bit more meaningful.

Comment: `Insert into Inventory.tableA` is itself wrong, it cannot execute as is. White spaces including new-lines are ignored so it is not likely that is the cause of the error. Perhaps you are reading and executing each line individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `singleline` mode

```
List<string> tables= Regex.Matches("yourInput",@"Insert into\s+(.*?)[\s\(]+"
,RegexOptions.Singleline|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
.Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Groups[1].Value)
.ToList<string>();

//tables contains all the table names
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your regex is, but you could:

1. Change all spaces in your regex to `\s+`.
2. Replace all endlines with `" "` first, then run it through your regex.

Answer (score 1):

\s will ignore all whitespace, so by using \s+ it will skip over tabs & CRLF. Since your examples had ;, we will capture all text that is not ;. If there is a space between, then use [^;\s]+ instead.

```
string text = @"Insert into  
    Inventory.tableA;
    Insert into Orders;";

    var tableNames = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?:Insert into\s+)(?<Name>[^;]+)(?:;)")
                          .OfType<Match>()
                          .Select (mt => mt.Groups["Name"].Value);

    Console.WriteLine ("Tables: {0}", string.Join(" ", tableNames));            

    /* Tables: Inventory.tableA Orders */
```